# Amplify authorization rule based on attribute value

Tags: authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a user, community and post type where a community can have multiple users and posts. The posts has an attribute called "visibility", if the visibility value is "private" only the users of that community can see the posts. If the visibility is "public" every user can see the post. Is possible to accomplish this using amplify and cognito? How?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito has [groups](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/). You can create groups and add users into these groups. When your user authenticates they get a token, and the claims on that token can be used to confirm which groups they belong to.

Cognito Groups are really useful for controlling access to things like admin apis with an 'admin' group. However, if you're creating lots of groups of adding users in and out regularly, I would recommend implementing an application level feature (i.e. manage this in your database).

Cognito isn't as scalable as your application persistence is likely to be. It can be a bit slow and it doesn't come with nice features for managing your groups.

So yes, its possible to manage in Cognito, but I would recommend doing it with a database of some sort.

Comment: I thought about doing this on application, but how can i do this without need to rewrite every query/mutation? Since one of the benefits of using amplify is the auto generated operations I think I'd lose that if I choose to implement an application level feature.